# How to pull type from Properties Settings StringName in C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I am performing dependency injection.

I am wanting to Bind an interface to an object which could change.
What I am doing is setting up several different connections so they all interact the same way. I want the option to point to one object or another, but I would like this manageable via the config.

So here is my problem.

I am currently able to do this:

```
kernal.Bind<InterfaceName>().To<ObjectName>(); // This works with no errors
```

What I am trying to do is pass in the ObjectName via property settings

Something like this.

```
kernal.Bind<InterfaceName>().To<Properties.Settings.Default.ObjectName>();
```

This of course doesn't work because it is trying to set a property to a type.

So here is what I have tried.

I have set the properties ObjectName then done the following.

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(Properties.Settings.Default.ObjectName);

kernal.Bind<InterfaceName>().To<myType>();
```

I cannot Resolve myType.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the syntax you are using, I'm assuming that you are using Ninject?

If so, you'll need to name the instance you are binding to:

```
kernal.Bind<InterfaceName>()
.To<ObjectName>()
.Named(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectingRepository);
```

Then you can request it using:

```
kernel.Get<InterfaceName>(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectingRepository);
```

The [Ninject wiki](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) has a few more examples.

Comment: What he want is to configure the IoC with a type only know at runtime, since in his 2nd example he is trying to use `Type.GetType`

Comment: @sgrassie The "ObjectName" is what I'm trying to get, ObjectName cannot be resolved

Comment: You and I read the question in different ways then, @Tseng. I believe he can achieve what he wants using named instances.

@Demodave, in my example, the `kernel.Get<InterfaceName>(..)` would be an instance of `ObjectName`.

Comment: @sgrassie Maybe I've updated my code to clarify, what object name is for

Answer (score 0):

For Generics, the type must be know at compile time! 
So you can't use any `Type` Variable.

What you want however is called abstract factory. Instead of injecting your `InterfaceName` to your constructors, you inject the abstract factory and resolve/create it at runtime.

```
interfaceFactory.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectingRepository);
```

and implement your resolve/creation logic there

Comment: So you are saying create a generic factory that bassed off what is passed in, I then set my interface and object class? I created factory already for the injection, let me see if I can pass in the properties that way.

Comment: I still have the same exact issue. I cannot put the To<objectName>, But I did like the Passing of properties It eliminated more code.

Comment: I never said you can use it as `To<T>`. T type would need to be know at **compile** time. You can't use a variable in `To<T>`. What you can do is pass a variable as parameter of the function. For Ninject, when the type is know at compile type, you use `kernel.Get<T>()`. When it's **not** know at compile type, you have to  use `kernel.Get(typeof(T))` where T is a class name, or from string: `kernel.Get(Type.GetType("Namespace.Subnamespace.ClassName, ..."))`, it would be inside your factory within `.Create` Method,where you also insure that the passed class name implements your desired interface

Comment: I think your confusion comes from not understanding how generics work in C#. You should read bit more about this topic, it's basic knowledge for modern OOP

Comment: I've tried to do typeof(Properties.Settings.Default.ObjectName), but it didn't like it